# Approximation to maximum and minimum function : soft-min and soft-max

Tags: math, statistics

The approximation to the function max(x) can be written as a "noisy-OR" as given below:

> max<sub>k</sub> x = 1 - Π<sub>k</sub>(1 - x)

Are there any way to approximate min(x)?

Answer (score 1):

If your values range between 0 and 1, then max is similar to the OR operator and min is similar to the AND operator. Similarly, the NOT operator can be thought of as 1 - x. Using De Morgan's laws, they're related by

> x<sub>1</sub> ∧ x<sub>2</sub> ∧ x<sub>3</sub> ...  ∧ x<sub>k</sub> = (not x<sub>1</sub>) ∨ (not x<sub>2</sub>) ∨ ... ∨ (not x<sub>k</sub>)

Therefore, you should be able to approximate min{x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>k</sub>} by computing 1 - max{1 - x<sub>1</sub>, 1 - x<sub>2</sub>, ..., 1 - x<sub>k</sub>}.

Hope this helps!